# Windows 8 System.exe writes to HDD like crazy

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, lag, io

I have checked Application event logs and found that every second about 20 entries for MSSQL Server were recorded. Removed the server and all its components and the problem is gone... Thanks everyone for tips!

I have a problem with Windows 8: System.exe starts accessing the hard drive and writing/reading like crazy for like 5-10minutes, it does it every 5 minutes and at the time the computer lags like crazy, even mouse and keyboard are unusable... 
Is there any way to either get rid of this crazy reading/writing? What can I check or do to figure out what is causing it? It is fairly recent problem, started few days ago. I can't think of anything unusual (software or driver updates) done at that time...
In Task Manager I can see SSD activity at 100%, in Resource Monitor I can see System.exe writing/reading sometimes 40-50 files at a time...
Below I attach some screen shots:

1#
[image: 1#]

2#
[image: 2#]

3#
[image: 3#]

Any help appreciated, this thing drives me nuts...

Comment: To whoever down-voted - an explanation why would be nice^^

Comment: Something is causing your system to generated a SOFTWARE.log file.  Have you looked into trying to update the firmware to your SSD?  This a new problem or an existing problem?

Comment: It is a new problem, started few days ago... I will try to update the firmware, thanks for the tip

Comment: Its hard to figure out what your actual question is besides "Help!" which isn't a good question. Furthermore I have numerious qustions about the system configuration which you left out.  I would try using a system restore point, there is likely new software you installed, causing the SOFTWARE.LOG file being written to.  I would look into how to disable the log file, because, you are writting a good amount of data every second.

Comment: Then tell me what info I should add and I will, I am not a person experienced with troubleshooting operating systems or hardware problems, so if I didn't include something means only that I didn't know I should....

Comment: Some hardware information that would be helpful.  Processor, SSD Model, Recent Software Installations just to name a few.  As a way to improve the question, phrase an actual question, its a sticking point ( some might disagree ) but a question should actually have a question contained within it.  This allows people with a similar question to locate your question.

Comment: There is no such thing as `System.exe` by the way, it's just `System`. :)

Comment: Hi, is it still the case? Here are some hints http://slopjong.de/2013/04/23/extremely-high-disk-activity-with-windows-8-and-how-to-fix-it/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

I experienced very similar problems to this when I first started using an SSD on . I followed an excellent guide on the overclock.net forum that managed to sort this issue out for me.

There are two versions of the guide one for [Windows 7](http://www.overclock.net/t/1156654/seans-windows-7-install-optimization-guide-for-ssds-hdds) and the other for [Windows 8](http://www.overclock.net/t/1240779/seans-windows-8-install-optimization-guide-for-ssds-hdds)

**Note:**

You **do not** need to follow the preinstallation instructions to the letter, they improve performance but are not absolutely necessary. His post Windows installation instructions will help you the most.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it backup the registry. See the Task Scheduler or set of backup software.

Comment: This looks to be more of a comment than a real answer.

Comment: the amount of the data does not look like a registry-backup